# can I bind a child function to the window resize event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code:

```
$('#myelem').click(function() {

height=$(this).height();
wh=$(window).height();

if (wh>height) {
// do stuff
}

});
```

What I want to do is bind the if clause to the window resize event. I tried putting it into a new child function but I can't pass the variables height,wh to it. I don't even know if what I am trying is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: you mean bind to resize right? then this should do it.. http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I want to bind it on both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a common function as handler of two distinct events

```
var elem = $('#myelem'); //caching a reference to $('#myelem')
var w    = $(window);    //caching a reference to $(window)

function doSomething() {
  var height = elem.height(),
      wh     = w.height();

  if (wh > height) {
     ...
  }
}

elem.on('click', function() { 
  doSomething();
});

w.on('resize', function() { 
  doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Or: `elem.on('click', doSomething);`